# PnP Modern Search (v4): Use page property (lookup) in query

Tags: token, pnp-search-webparts

Here is the situation:

I have a document library *Images* in which images are stored that are tagged through a lookup column (named *ImagesColumn*) which is fed by a list. This lookup column is mapped to *RefinableString110*.

I now want to create multiple pages in which the PnP Search Result Web part dynamically only displays images for certain values of *ImagesColumn*. To do so, I created a column in the site pages library called *PagesColumn*.

This approach works in principle when using this query:

```
path:"https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxxx/Images/*" RefinableString110:{Page.PagesColumn}
```

However, it only works when *PagesColumn* is a single line of text. When *PagesColumn* is a lookup column retrieving data from the same list as *ImagesColumn*, I get 0 results. This is problematic since I need both Images and Webpages to get their data from the same list, or otherwise it wouldn't be truly dynamic.

Does anyone know a solution to this issue?

Many thanks!